# Не отображается активность на табло коммитов в GitHub при коммитах через Git

Tags: git, github

Когда я делаю коммиты в гитхаб-репозиторий через гит, на табло не отображаются изменения. При этом я прописал user-name и email в git, и если я захожу на сделанный коммит в самом репозитории, там будет моя аватарка и ник гитхаба. Можете пожалуйста помочь решить проблему?

Comment: А вы их пушите? (если да, вы в той же ветке смотрите?) Что пишет консоль после пуша?

Comment: Про какое табло идет речь?

Comment: @user7860670 про табло с мелкими серыми и зелеными квадратами.

Comment: @had0uken после пуша пишет: 

Enumerating objects: 32, done.
Counting objects: 100% (32/32), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
Writing objects: 100% (23/23), 3.22 KiB | 471.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 23 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (7/7), completed with 2 local objects.
To https://github.com/IvanZemsky/react-users-list-1.git
   8cf5b7d..65b5f8d  master -> master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите на картинке, вы пушите ваши комиты не в дефолтную ветку, а в master. Поэтому эти коммиты не появляются у вас на графе.

В соответствии с документацией гита:

> Commits will appear on your contributions graph if they meet
> all of the following conditions:
>
> The email address used for the commits is associated with your account
> on GitHub.com.
>
> The commits were made in a standalone repository, not a
> fork.
>
> The commits were made: In the repository's default branch In the
> gh-pages branch (for repositories with project sites)

смотрите третий пункт: считаются только коммиты, которые были в дефолтной ветке

Comment: Я изменил основную ветвь и всё заработало. Спасибо!